# How do I access the controller I declared for an angularjs directive in the templateUrl?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I would like to use a directive with a controller but I would like to access the same controller in the url template. How can I do this? For example, I would like something along the lines of:

```
<my-directive ng-click="myController.doSomething()"></my-directive>
```

which would have the same effect if I didn't make a custom directive and declared

```
<div ng-controller="MyController as myController" ng-click="myController.doSomething()"></div>
```

Note: I am not looking for a solution that uses jquery to bind the click behaviour in the link function.

Clarification: I'm using typescript with angularjs, and the I want to do something like the following:

```
export class Controller {
  public items = [item1, item2, item3];

  public doSomething() {
    // do something
  }
}

export class MyDirective implements ng.IDirective {
  public templateUrl = "path/to/url";
  public controller = Controller;
  public link = // whatever my link function does;
}
```

And in the template

```
<div ng-repeat="item in Controller.items" ng-click="Controller.doSomething()></div>
```

except that I don't know actually how I would refer to the controller used by the directive. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Lets start by interacting with a fiddle to try and figure out exactly what you want to achieve. This one currently contains a directive that you can click on, and perform some internal directive logic.

http://jsfiddle.net/3EFH4/

It uses `elem.on()` instead of `ng-click` to catch the event. If you definitely want to use a controller to process the click, you need to explain why, and whether or not it needs to be external to the directive (this is usually because of changeable data that needs to interact).

Comment: This doesn't seem to scale well the more functions I want to have... Also, I want to access the controller that I used when declaring the directive. In this case, there would have been a declaration
"controller: MyController"
for the directive.

Comment: Have you considered giving your directive a controller itself? You may have to explain in more detail what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I added some more detail. Thanks for the help!